# Sentencia MySQL para actualizar correctamente un registro existente desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Trato de actualizar los datos de un usuario pero, recibo el error de SQL Syntax:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(nombre,
>   apellido, usuario, contrasena, id_perfil)VALUES ('Test 1rrr', 'Prueba
>   1' at line 1

Al cliente hacer clic en el botón *actualizar*, hago esto:

```
dato_usuario.setId_usuario(Integer.parseInt(txtId_Usuario.getText()));
                dato_usuario.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
                dato_usuario.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
                dato_usuario.setUsuario(txtUsuario.getText());
                dato_usuario.setContrasena(txtContrasena.getText());
                dato_usuario.setId_perfil(cboPerfil.getSelectedIndex());

// Envío los datos a un método de otra clase que contiene todo para conectarse con MySQL
                if (logica_usuario.actualizar(dato_usuario)) {  // Si el método "actualizar" retorna true
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario ha sido actualizado.", "Éxito", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!, no se ha podido actualizar el usuario.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
```

**Código MySQL**:

```
public boolean actualizar(Dato_usuario d_usr) {
        sSQL =  "UPDATE usuario SET"
                + "(nombre, apellido, usuario, contrasena, id_perfil)"
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE id_usuario=?";

        boolean resultado;

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL)) {

            pstm.setString(1, d_usr.getNombre());
            pstm.setString(2, d_usr.getApellido());
            pstm.setString(3, d_usr.getUsuario());
            pstm.setString(4, d_usr.getContrasena());
            pstm.setInt(5, d_usr.getId_perfil());
            pstm.setInt(6, d_usr.getId_usuario());
            pstm.executeUpdate();

            resultado = true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: actualizar(Dato_usuario d_usr)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            resultado = false;
            }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Estoy tratando de indicarle que me actualice los datos del usuario con el `id_usuario = ?` pero, como el comodín `?` del `id_usuario` está ubicado en el último lugar, se lo paso como el número 6.

Realmente no sé si está correcto, soy novato con `SQL`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error qué te envía?

Comment: dice esto:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(nombre, apellido, usuario, contrasena, id_perfil)VALUES ('Test 1rrr', 'Prueba 1' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que tu sentencia de `SQL` en tu variable `sSQL` debería ser así para el `UPDATE`:

```
sSQL = "UPDATE usuario SET "
+ "nombre = ?"
+ ",apellido = ?"
+ ",usuario = ?"
+ ",contrasena = ?"
+ ",id_perfil = ? "
+ "WHERE id_usuario=?";
```

En el siguiente [link](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples) podrás encontrar un tutorial del uso de las sentencias `SQL` y su sintaxis para las operacines CRUD (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE`) utilizanndo `MySQL` y `Java`

Comment: ha funcionado pero, por qué los cambios en la sentencia, por qué el uso de comas y no el uso de VALUES ???, alguna razón?.

Comment: El uso de VALUES solo es correcto para la sentencia INSERT, para el UPDATE funciona un poco diferente. En el siguiente link http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples podrás encontrar un ejemplo de la operaciones CRUD (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) con Java y MySQL